# What setting locks local rotation and scaling of an object?

Tags: objects, transforms

I have encountered a strange phenomenon, it must be some key I hit but I have no idea what!

All of a sudden I noticed that nothing will rotate or scale in object mode in a project I am working on.  After playing around with some basic settings I noticed that when I set the *pivot center* to the *3d cursor* and try to rotate something it simply moves the object around the 3d cursor without rotating it.  Scaling the object moves it towards or away from the 3d cursor.  Here is a picture:

[image]

It seems that I have somehow locked local rotation and scaling of all objects, the only way I can rotate or scale anything is in edit mode.  How on earth did I do that and how do I turn it off?

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3626, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1308 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12303

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you have activated the *Manipulate Pivot Points* tool.  It's found directly to the right of the Pivot Point selection menu in *3D view > Header*.

Here's a demo.

[image]

It can also be toggled with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (comma).

Now, if you mistakenly press some keyboard shortcut that ends up causing you grief like this; you can try pulling down the top header bar to view the Info area.  It should contain most of what you've recently done.(to view EVERYTHING you'd have to enable debug logging, that's gets messy quickly)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I was almost done with a big project (for Andrew's Christmas competition) and was just trying to move things around for the final render when this happened.  I must have hit [Alt]+[,] inadvertently.  Is there somewhere (an addon maybe) that can give a short history of keys I have hit or actions I have done that I can look at when I do something like this?

Comment: Pull down the top header bar to view the Info area, it lists all the tools you've used.  It's very useful for scripting.  That's actually a good idea to for an answer like this.  I'll add it.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't even think of that, that will be really helpful!  Is there a way to associate the python with the keyboard shortcut though?

Comment: There is a document posted on GITHUB by Jonathan Williamson https://github.com/carter2422/blender-presets/blob/master/keyconfig/blender_default.py I assume it's complete.  Search for the operator, the line above should be the key-binding.  I just did a quick check on the tool used here and it's in the list with the correct keys.